# Variables in errors ajax+jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, error-handling

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var chanels_elems = document.getElementsByClassName('chanels');
        var ids = [];
        var urls = [];
        var i = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < chanels_elems.length; i++) {
            ids[i] = chanels_elems[i].id;
            urls[i] = $('#' + ids[i]).attr('url');
        }

        for (i = 0; i < chanels_elems.length; i++) {
            var id = ids[i];
            $.ajax({
                url: '{{ Url.media('ajax/testajax') }}',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {id: ids[i], url: urls[i]},
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.status == '1') {
                        $('#span_' + result.id).attr('class', 'label label-success').empty().append('true');
                    }
                    if (result.status == '2') {
                        $('#span_' + result.id).attr('class', 'label label-danger').empty().append('false');
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    $('#span_' + ids[i]).attr('class', 'label label-info').empty().append('error');
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

ids[i] in error handler is undefined, and var id = ids[i]; undefined too. Why? What can i do with this problem?
ids[i] in error handler is undefined, and var id = ids[i]; undefined too. Why? What can i do with this problem?

Comment: Check `ids ` value after first for loop. It is probably empty

Comment: It is empty in all iterations of the loop

Comment: you are trying to get ith index of empty array, so I am asking you: Is it normal to get undefined?

Answer (score 0):

This is a really bad way to make a ajax call.Make just one ajax call with all ids and urls.Send back an array with ids and status.Use this for your JS.If you could show your php page I can help with it too.Try this

```
var myArr={};
$('.chanels').each(function(){
    myArr[$(this).attr('id')]=$(this).attr('href');//Use whatever you need about the url.
});

$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'your url',
    data:myArr,
    dataType:'JSON',
    success:function(result)
    {

    }
});
```

You are pinging the server too many times.

Comment: Will this `data:{data_arr:myArr}` work? Use `data:JSON.stringify(myArr)` instead

Answer (score 0):

Note, when your callbacks are called, var i is in last value of array. You should use passing by copy of var. Something like that.

```
for (i = 0; i < chanels_elems.length; i++) {
(function(i) {
    var id = ids[i];
    $.ajax({
        url: '{{ Url.media('ajax/testajax') }}',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {id: ids[i], url: urls[i]},
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.status == '1') {
                $('#span_' + result.id).attr('class', 'label label-success').empty().append('true');
            }
            if (result.status == '2') {
                $('#span_' + result.id).attr('class', 'label label-danger').empty().append('false');
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            $('#span_' + ids[i]).attr('class', 'label label-info').empty().append('error');
        }
    });
})(i);
}
```

And try to look at console.log(ids); before the last "for".